# Wierd Syntax - Underscores between digits

Tags: java, syntax

Per my usual, I have been working on more UIL Java practice sheets when I came across this problem:

```
int _ = 8;
System.out.println(5_5);
```

The question was "What is the output of the following code piece?"

My first guess was a syntax error, but the correct response is actually **55**.

Why is this?

Comment: @arshajii: Did you ever consider why you had to shorten that URL?

Comment: This is probably a FAQ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Java 7, you can have underscores in between digits, to improve readability:

From [JLS - Section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) and [JLS Section 3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> Underscores are allowed as separators between digits that denote the integer.

For floating point literal also:

> Underscores are allowed as separators between digits that denote the whole-number part, and between digits that denote the fraction part, and between digits that denote the exponent.

For e.g., `1000000000` can now be written as `1_000_000_000`. So, it is better for eyes, isn't it.

Similarly you can write - `0x7fff_ffff`, `0b0111_1111`.

And regarding variable name, `_` is a valid variable name. As per Java standard, a variable name should start with a `$`, `_` or a `letter`.

Comment: +1 didn't know you couldn't use this for floating point.

Comment: I think this is heinous.  Improve readability?  I disagree.

Comment: @duffymo. I think this was for readability purpose majorly. Writing `1_000_000_000` is better readable than `1000000000`.

Comment: It make sense for long numbers like `1_000_000_000` I am used to writing `1000*1000*1000`

Comment: I'm more hung up on the fact _ is a valid variable name (never knew that). Seems horrible!

Comment: @RohitJain "better readable" it is.

Comment: @AndrewMartin That is just the start there is loads of symbols you can use, some of them have a zero width or make every character after them appear backwards, mwahahaha.  http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-code.html and http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/uses-for-special-characters-in-java-code.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey: If I ever get made redundant, I know what I'm doing on my last day :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Those are some nice variable names. I should start to use it, when I want to scare fellow programmers :)

Comment: ⁀ ‿ ⁀ Try running this code in a main method, This really does compile and run. It print a list of the odd characters you can use `for (char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++)
        if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c⁯‮h) && !Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c⁯‮h))
            System.out.printf("%04x <%s>%n", (int) c⁯‮h, "" + c⁯‮h);
` .....................................................  So backward lol

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Auuwaa. Auwaaa. That's like a suicide pill.

Comment: @PeterLawrey. ROFL.. I can't go forward, 'coz I've to go backward to move forward. Holy freak, it does give an output. That is evil. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Seems like underscores work for floating point literals too - `12.145_34` compiles perfectly fine. Though it's not specified in JLS. :( I guess, I'll give a deeper look.

Comment: @RohitJain I bet the parser for integers and floating point share code because it didn't matter before.

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Well, it is actually defined for numerical literal. So, floating point literal also comes in. I missed that part earlier.