# What was the rationale for allowing underscores between integer digits?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, literals

I stumbled across this seemingly odd statement in the JLS, section [3.10.1 (integer literals)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) today:

> Underscores are allowed as separators between digits that denote the integer.

Lo and behold the following is completely valid ([example](http://ideone.com/uyGzsg)):

```
int x = 1_2_3_4_5____6;
```

Underscores may only appear *between* digits, leading/trailing underscores are invalid.

What was the rationale for this? Is it some holdover from some other language? Some style that was common at the time? It seems like a rather strange thing to allow.

Comment: What is more readable to you: `5236323` or `5_236_323`?

Comment: Nevermind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175809/wierd-syntax-underscores-between-digits?rq=1.

Comment: @Flown Yeah. The dupe says readability too. Deleting this. Or not, now it's answered. (Also huh, there's a whole chain of dupes here that didn't come up in the auto-search. Fun!)

Comment: *Is it some holdover from some other language?* It was added in Java 7, so no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind this is to be able to display a big number that is easily readable.

Example: `int x = 1_000_000;`

There are other use cases for this but this is the most used i think.

See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) for more information.

Comment: Kinda handy. I might start doing that.

Comment: Whoa there, [keep your pants on](https://i.snag.gy/qIzc6h.jpg). There's a 15 minute time limit on accepts. I might wait until tomorrow just to keep you on the edge of your seat! :D

Comment: @JeroenVandevelde No need for that. Just write more answers and the points will come.